# compare two arrays in PHP and get the difference in key

Tags: php, arrays

I have been reading through the manual to find a function that does what I want but I ended up doing it myself. I want to compare two arrays and calculate the difference between the keys. Or more practically analyse the difference in order of the values.

I have done this as follows, but I have a feeling this can be done better.

if anyone has an idea how to improve this please let me know becasue im eager to improve.

```
<?php
$goodarray = array(300,250,200,150,100);

$usersupliedarray = array(250,300,200,150,100); // first two spots are wrong

$score = count($goodarray);

foreach($usersupliedarray as $key => $value){

    $arraykey = array_search($value, $goodarray);

    $difference = abs($key-$arraykey);

    $score = $score + $difference;


    echo "$value $goodarray[$key] ($difference = $score) <hr />";

}
```

Comment: This question is unclear and has an incomplete [mvce] because it is missing the clarity that comes with presenting the exact desired output from the sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_map` with a void callback can come in handy here, for example,

```
$a = array(300,250,200,150,100);
$b = array(250,300,200,150,100);

$faults = 0;
foreach(array_map(null, $a, $b) as $x)
    $faults += $x[0] != $x[1]; // x[0] is $a element, x[1] is $b

print $faults; // 2
```

UPD: if you want to compute distances between equal elements, and not just count differences, your original code looks just fine to me. One improvement which can be made is to get rid of inefficient `array_search` and to use  an "inverted index" of the first array instead:

```
foreach($a as $pos => $val)
    $inv[$val] = $pos;
```

or just

```
$inv = array_flip($a);
```

and then

```
foreach($b as $pos => $val)
    $score += abs($pos - $inv[$val]);
```

Comment: HI Georg, I'll have to take a closer look at your code ;) Thanks I'll let you know once i have fully understood it.

Comment: Ha Georg thanks for showing me the array_map with a void call back, i now see it makes an array of arrays. What im looking for though is way to value the difference in the order of the values. so if someone is one step off it's only 1 but if someone is  3 steps off he is "penelized" with 3. Anyway your example gave me enough new information to make your post usefull. Thanks for that! +1

Comment: @rinserepeat: oops, looks like I misread the question! I've updated my post.

Comment: Ha Georg, thanks alot for the suggestion. Really appreciate it. Learning everyday :)

Comment: Ha Georg, that inverted index is super smart! By interchanging the keys with the values its indeed super easy to compare the positions. Thanks alot for teaching me this stuff! Would array_flip ()  contribute this or is that too much overhead.

Comment: @rinserepeat: glad it helped. Yes, `array_flip` is a good idea, updated the answer.